# Appending text to slider text (display_selector)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, foundation.js

I'm trying to append $ symbol to slider label generated using Foundation.js framework, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/z3h8gzqb/) and here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-10 medium-11 columns">
         <div class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="display_selector: #sliderOutput3;">
           <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
             <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="small-2 medium-1 columns">
          <span id="sliderOutput3"></span>
            </div>
      </div>
```

The current label is generated from `id="sliderOutput3"` and is passed using `data-slider data-options="display_selector: #sliderOutput3;"`

I've been trying from couple of hours to add $ symobol to the label, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally on_change method could be used something like this

```
$(document).foundation({
    slider: {
        on_change: function () {
            var value = $('.range-slider').attr('data-slider');
            $('#sliderOutput3').html(value + '$');
        }
    }
}).foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

*HOWEVER THIS WILL NOT WORK.*

From the source code it looks like foundation.js [triggers `on_change`(source)](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.slider.js#L163) and then [sets the value(source)](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.slider.js#L177) to #sliderOutput . Which means whatever is done to #sliderOutput in `on_change` will be overridden.

You have two options

#### Option 1

Have another span with $ symbol. Like this

```
<div class="small-2 medium-1 columns"> 
  <span id="sliderOutput3"></span>
  <span>$</span>
</div>
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/z3h8gzqb/2/**

#### Option 2

Use settimeout inside on_change method like this

```
on_change: function () {
  var value = $('.range-slider').attr('data-slider');
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#sliderOutput3').html(value + '$');
  }, 0);
}
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/z3h8gzqb/4/**

I would personally recommend option 1. Option 2 will work but with a delay and just doesn't feel right.

Comment: Adding an other <span> was the easiest option. Congrats on reaching 10k :)